# Is there a comfortable, secure, light, and cheap sling shoulder strap system?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-straps

I'm looking to carry my Canon DSLR on my shoulder.

I have a Canon T1i with 15-85mm lens that I walked around with all the time.

Here is what I need:

- A comfortable strap that is long enough to carry on shoulder
- It holds the camera security and in place (maybe behind my back or by the side, lens pointing downward)
- It is easy to sling around and ready to shoot in seconds
- It is fairly light and I can carry my camera on my shoulder for hours
- It is fairly cheap (something in the $20 range)

I read about Sun snipper the RS system. They're pretty expensive. I am wondering if there is a cheaper alternative that is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several DIY solutions been posted online, here's a few I found:

- [Sling Your Camera With A DIY C-Loop For Under $5](http://diyphotography.net/sling-your-camera-with-a-diy-c-loop-for-under-5)
- [Camera Sling / Luma Loop Re:Make](http://abella.net/?page_id=140)
- [Shoot Quickly With A DIY Glide Strap](http://www.diyphotography.net/shoot-quickly-with-a-diy-glide-strap)

Besides the well known sling solution [C-Loop](http://www.customslr.com/products/c-loop), [BlackRapid](http://www.blackrapid.com/) and [SunSniper](http://www.sun-sniper.com/), there's also a **[Quick Strap](http://www.qstrap.co.uk/singleqstrap.html)** that is known for its low end pricing. You can easily find Quick Straps on eBay for under US$20 and I have also seen them in local camera shops.

Personally, I own a BlackRapid RS-Sport and bought 1 for my colleague as gift. We mutually agreed, this is the best camera gear investment we've (or more precisely, I've) made. Not only it is comfortable and fast reaching, You know it is a professional gear and will not drop your camera upside down. Besides, unlike flash diffusers, you will only bound to have 1 strap and you will always be using it, so you might as well as invest into a trusty product that will hand on to your $1000+ camera and lens!

Comment: Can you please tell me what's difference between RS4, RS5, RS7 & RS Sport? Thanks

Comment: @rvpals, if you visit the BlackRapid product pages you shall see distinguishable descriptions on these 4 products. Keep in mind, they are all fundamentally the same just with different minor tweak for specific likings. For instance, I run, chase and jump around when I photographs, RS-Sport provides 'under arm strap' which will tight lock the strap on your shoulder. I have even rock climbed with this strap.

Comment: C-Loop looks really cool since it lets you choose your own comfy strap. Can't wait they make one that doubles as a quick-release plate too :)

Comment: I ended up buying a RS-7. I haven't take it out on a field trip yet, but seems expensive for such little device, but it looks very sturdy that I trust my camera hanging off the belt.

Comment: I have been using RS-7 for a few years now. Here's what I can say about it: 1. It's probably the best strap I can get. It keeps the camera safely hanging out by your side and you can jump into action quickly. 2. It's good for this purpose only and still it's not comfortable having the camera on a RS-7 and walk for a longer period of time, due to the weight of everything, still more comfortable to have your camera in a backpack but you're missing the ready to shoot quick draw.

Comment: @rvpals, good to see you back after 5 years provide your feedback! As for myself after 5 years, I still have my RS-7 but I now sometime go without strap depends on the situation.

Comment: @Travis L. I used my RS-7 a lot for the past few years. RS-7 is good for walking around, but I have Canon T1i and a 15-85 which is quite heavy. So it's just not comfortable walking around in it all day. The only option seems to be get one of those very bulky strapping system and have your camera hangs on your chest tightly.

Answer (score 3):

You can get all the strapping and buckles and such from strapworks.com and then just get the [swivel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003BFTS9K) and [tripod lock](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003LA595M) on amazon.  It'll run you *far* cheaper than a whole strap from Black Rapid.

Comment: I see slingworks has a lot of options, what is close to the black rapid strap?

Comment: @dpollitt - whatever width you want, but something like https://www.strapworks.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=SAS1H and  this https://www.strapworks.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=PCB as a 'stop' for the camera.  Add a shoulder pad however you want.

Answer (score 1):

Search eBay for 'Camera Sling' and you'll find a bunch of them. I paid about $20 for mine including shipping from HK to Australia, not as nicely made as a Sun Sniper but it's been working well for me for the past year for my Nikon D3000. I would advise checking the carabiner swivel to make sure it's up to the task if you get one as this is a potential weak link, a replacement shouldn't be too hard to source if it isn't.

Comment: Do you have a link to the one you bought from Hong Kong ? Thanks.