# What camera strap works well with a 70-200mm lens?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-straps

After spending hours walking around with my stock strap, nearly screaming every time I had my 600D with a 70-200mm attached I have to say its time to try something new.

I found the [CUSTOMSLR](http://www.customslr.com), and the attachment which many other manufactures have, and my local photography store also deals with their products.

Whats the advantage of different straps for heavy lenses?

Comment: I have a D300 and have the same issue with the stock strap with the 70-200mm - sometimes it nearly came right off.

Comment: Basically any information on "what camera strap works best" is going to be weighing the decision heavily based on working with a 70-200mm lens, as that is very typical to have and a common reason to look for a better strap. For that reason, I think this is a just as good as a general "what are some good straps" question.

Comment: If you want a sling type, see http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18767/is-there-a-comfortable-secure-light-and-cheap-sling-shoulder-strap-system

Comment: What 70-200 is that? There's a pretty big difference between even just Canon's 70-200/4.0 L USM and their 70-200/2.8 L IS USM.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, its the smallest: 70-200/4.0L non-IS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost every time the "what strap" question comes up, my answer will be the same. Try the [Black Rapid](http://www.google.com/aclk?sa=l&ai=CQpAGGCb_T5K_Haa72QWB0aiVCNvv6bUCw-HLgCKD_ID4LQgAEAEguVRQorajw_z_____AWDJptWGyKPoGaAB5b_Y4wPIAQGqBBtP0FWc-YdTeyOjCyvbKJkL1rxZ8nUGmYaxyV-ABZBO&sig=AOD64_0ePxY_V7zyneY0kD-2rBKiNx8_Ow&ved=0CGMQ0Qw&adurl=http://www.blackrapid.com/product/camera-strap/snapr20/) strap. With the 70-200, the lens faces directly downward, allowing you to both stabilize the lens against motion as you walk, and keep it from hitting things.

I've carried that exact lens with my Black Rapid and it's so amazingly better than a stock camera strap, I've never gone back. In fact, I can't make a case to go back to a standard strap for any body/lens combination.

Comment: I have limited access to trying out different manufactures, so i was hoping for more hands-on, especially with large lenses. But Black Rapid was similiar to my aim, which im happy to hear.

Comment: I don't know what more hands-on means, but I personally have used Black Rapid and that 70-200 lens on my 1DsMIII and 5DMkII. Both work great. Were you looking to try one out for yourself? If so, contact the manufacturer (Black Rapid) and see whether someone in your area carries these straps.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea. I will contact Black Rapid and see if im lucky to find a dealer nearby!

Comment: From the other side: I can't imagine a case being made for any strap that claims sovereignty over the tripod socket for general photography. I really don't understand how the BR strap and its like leaked out of the run-and-gun photojournalism realm.

Comment: It doesn't claim the tripod socket if you are using one of those handy floppy mount plates -- just hook the strap to the D-ring. If you're using a tripod, you're more likely to need a good bag than a good strap anyhow. Neh?